# How to set different Default Page in NOPCommerce2.65

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I want to set different default page in nop2.65, i have register new Route

```
//In RouteProvider
//Custome page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CustomHome",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Customer", action = "Login" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

            //home page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

it's  work fine set Login Page as Default but when i click on "Home" menu it redirect login page
instead of home page.
i have also tried to set default page in Global.asax file that also not work

```
//In Global.asax file
    routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution in NOP2.65 all route register under NOP.Web->Infrastructure->RouteProvider.cs. if you want to set different route then your RouteProvider.cs like

```
/In RouteProvider
//Custome page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CustomHome",
                            "", // Route name
                            new { controller = "Customer", action = "Login" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

            //home page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                            "home/", // Route name
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

NOTE: Set **RouteName** as blank for newly register route  and modified HomePage RouteName.